# C# LINQ question

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a series of type `List<Int32>` and another series of `List<ClassA>`, where `ClassA`
has the following representation :

```
public ClassA
{
  public String PropertyA {get; set;}
  public List<Int32> PropertyB {get; set;}
  public String PropertyC {get; set;}
}
```

I want to retrieve using LINQ a series of type `List<KeyValuePair<PropertyC, Int32>>` where `Int32` is contained within `List<Int32>` `PropertyB`.
Can this be done using one linq statement?

Comment: so you will have a list of classA objects? Can you clarify the question a little bit

Comment: Could you give us an example ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question.  By series, do you mean an array?  Are you saying you want a LINQ query that gets all the `ClassA` objects that contain a specific value (the int) in their `PropertyB`?

Comment: Can you give an example the input and the output that you want

Comment: You actually want a List<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>> I believe, PropertyC does not appear to be a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
var query = (from x in listOfInt32s
             from y in listOfClassAs
             where y.PropertyB.Contains(x)
             select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(y.PropertyC, x))
            .ToList();
```

... but I'm not entirely sure.

(As per the comments, I've changed the first `KeyValuePair` type argument to `string`.)

Comment: +1 based on the given question I think this is the most likely answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = (from i in listOfInts
         from a in listOfA
         where
              a.PropertyB.Contains(i)
         select new KeyValuePair<String, int>(a.PropertyC, i))
         .ToList();
```

Comment: I think OP wanted just the integer contained in the list, you returned the whole ClassA object in the key value pair. PropertyB will contain the integer he wants but will also have integers that did not fit the criteria. Basically your KVP type is off.

Comment: @Richard: yes, but 4 minutes late
@marr75: She wants the int out of the List<Int32>, the i in my answer and PropertyC out of the matchin ClassA objects. I corrected the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you mean by "where Int32 is contained within `List<Int32> PropertyB`".  I'm interpreting it to mean that you want the value part of the KeyValuePair to be some integer that's in PropertyB.  In the example below I pick the first one.

```
List<ClassA> myList = GetListOfStuff(); //However you get the list
var results = from myList
              select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(a.PropertyC, a.PropertyB.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var idList = GetIdList(); //List of integer
var objectList = GetObjectList(); //List of ClassA
var pairs = objectList
    .SelectMany(item => item.PropertyB
        .Select(id => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item.PropertyC, id)))
    .Where(item => idList.Contains(item.Value));
```